# Is the infimum of (Riemann) Upper Sum equal to the limit of Upper Sum as partition size goes to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I am following notation in Wheedon and Zygmund, let the (Riemann) upper sum be $U_\Gamma=\sum_{k=1}^N[\sup_{x\in I_k}f(x)]v(I_k)$, and let $\Gamma=\{I_k\}$ a partition of $I$ into finite nonoverlapping intervals, and let $|\Gamma|=\max_k(diam I_k)$.

My question is are the two equal:

1) $\inf_\Gamma U_\Gamma$

2) $\lim_{|\Gamma|\to 0} U_\Gamma$

What I can see is that if $\Gamma'$ is a refinement of $\Gamma$, certainly $U_\Gamma'\leq U_\Gamma$. However it is not immediately clear why the two are equal (or are they)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume $|f| \le M <\infty.$ Denote the infimum over all upper sums by $L.$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ Choose a partition $P$ such that $U(P) < L + \epsilon.$ Let $n$ be the number of subintervals induced by $P.$ We can assume $n>1.$ Finally, let $\delta = \epsilon/[(n-1)(M+1)].$

Now let $Q$ be a partition such that $|Q| < \delta.$ A subinterval of $Q$ may contain a point of $P$ in its interior. There can be no more than $n-1$ such subintervals (thanks to @yoyostein for improving my first estimate of $2n$.) The subsum of $U(Q)$ corresponding to these subintervals is therefore no more than

$$(n-1)M\delta < \epsilon.$$

All the other subintervals of $Q$ are contained in subintervals of $P.$ The subsum of $U(Q)$ corresponding to these subintervals is therefore no more than $U(P).$

Adding these subsums shows

$$L \le U(Q) < \epsilon + (L + \epsilon) = L + 2\epsilon.$$

This gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain more about the part where "there cannot be more than 2n such subintervals"? Why is that so?

Comment: Can 2n be replaced by n-1, which is the number of "boundaries" of the n subintervals?

Comment: You are right, $n-1$ works. And it's a neater upper bound. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $(1)$ as the definition of $\overline \int f$,

let $\epsilon >0$, and find a partition $\Gamma $ such that

$U_{\Gamma }-\overline \int f <\epsilon$.

Now take any refinement $\Gamma'$ of $\Gamma.\ $Then, $\vert \Gamma' \vert \le \vert \Gamma \vert $ and

$\overline \int f \le U_{\Gamma' }\le U_{\Gamma }$ which means that

$U_{\Gamma' }-\overline \int f <\epsilon$.

This is true for $all$ refinements of $\Gamma$, so in fact

$\lim_{|\Gamma'|\to 0} U_\Gamma'-\overline \int f <\epsilon.$

(One way to see this: choose a sequence of partitions $\Gamma'_n\subseteq \Gamma'_{n+1 }$ such that $\vert \Gamma'_n\vert <\min (1/n,\vert \Gamma \vert) $. Then, $U_{\Gamma_n' }-\overline \int f <\epsilon$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$).

Thus, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal.

Comment: I can see that the statement is true for all refinements of $\Gamma$, but what happens for partitions that is not a refinement of $\Gamma$?